# Movie where people communicate with a spirit using dice

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

In the movie I watched, I think there was a man who is killing people at the behest of his mother's spirit, though I'm not sure on that part.

There was a scene where a group of characters communicates with this woman's spirit using dice. One person would ask her a question and then roll dice with letters on them. That person would then make out what words these dice spell out. In one instance, they ask the spirit what they will find at their location, to which the dice spell out "Mors". One of the characters realizes that this means "Death" in Latin just as the spirit drops a chandelier on them, but they manage to dodge it.

Then, the killer tells the others to ask her what is behind his back, and the other characters comply. The spirit's answer is "Knife", at which point I think the killer starts attacking them, though I'm not sure about that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ***[Insidious: Chapter 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insidious:_Chapter_2)*** (2013).

> *Insidious: Chapter 2* is a 2013 American supernatural horror film directed by James Wan. The film is a sequel to 2010's Insidious, the second installment in the Insidious franchise, and the fourth in terms of the series' in-story chronology. The film stars Patrick Wilson and Rose Byrne, reprising their roles as Josh and Renai Lambert, a husband and wife who seek to uncover the secret that has left them dangerously connected to the spirit world.

One of the characters, Carl (played by Steve Coulter), uses letter dice to communicate with the spirit world.

In one scene, about an hour into the movie, he asks a spirit *"Why did you bring us here? What are we looking for?"*. He then drops several letter dice onto a table, four of which spell the word 'mors'; Carl recognises this as Latin for 'death'. Moments later, a chandelier falls, almost striking a woman standing in the same room, but Carl manages to push her out of the way.

In a later scene, he asks another character *"What have you got behind your back?"*. The other character responds *"Why don't you ask your dice what I have behind my back?"*. Carl drops the dice onto a table again, and five of them spell the word 'knife'. The other character then immediately attacks Carl with the knife.

The official trailer doesn't show either scene, but you can briefly see the letter dice at the 1:09 mark.